# Is it OK to post a link to my question in the general chat room, to publicize it?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, chat, best-practice

If I ask a question and want to draw attention to it, is it OK to post links to it in the general chat room? Or is this considered bad, since there is already a questions feed and if lots of people manually posted links to their questions in chat, the chat room might be overwhelmed?

Please note that I am not asking if it is OK for me to to *eventually* post a link to my question in chat, to draw attention to it. I'm assuming that if I wait a while without much response, and I am willing to discuss the question in chat, then this is OK (in moderation). Instead, I'm asking if it is OK for me to *immediately* post a link to it in chat, just a couple minutes after creating the question, to stimulate attention to it.

Comment: A touch of irony - your question just popped up in the feed in the General room :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually the preferred method of handling questions in chat. Typical workflow is: Ask question on Ask Ubuntu, paste link in chat to carry a discussion about the question, edit question to reflect new information discovered in chat, potentially have answer questioned - the answer of course being posted to the question on Ask Ubuntu.

As opposed to just asking a question in chat and having a conversation then getting an answer. That way your question can help other users in the future.